# Read string from double pointer C++ function with Python

Tags: python, c, pointers

I developed a DLL in C++ and I need to use all the functions with Python. As I'm a novice in Python (3.x) I have a problem to wrap a specific function.

Here the C function in my DLL. This function return the address of the string table which contain the name of the devices and the number of devices.

```
char dev[10][16];

void listDevices(char **devices, short *number)
{
   short n;

   // Process which recover devices string and number, here 2 devices       
   ...
   n=2;
   sprintf(dev[0],"%s","device0");
   sprintf(dev[1],"%s","device1");

   // Return the result
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++) devices[i]=dev[i];
   *number=n;
}
```

Here the little program in C (which works) to use this function:

```
char *devicesList[10];
int n=0;
listDevices(devicesList, &n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf(" -%u: %s\n", i, devicesList[i]);
```

The result:
 - 0: device0
 - 1: device1

Now I tried to do the same thing in Python but I have a "access violation writing" from the compilator. Here is my little program in Python :

```
  myDll= dllOpen(Dll)
  listDev = myDll.listDevices
  listDev.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(c_short)]
  devicesList = POINTER(c_char_p)()
  n = c_short()
  listDev(devicesList,byref(nDev)) 
  for i in range(n):
    print (devicesList[i])
```

I think I don't use a correct declaration of the table of pointer on string. I don't know how I can correctly declare it, so if you have a solution I will be very grateful.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not knowing Python ctypes very well, this is only a guess but I guess that the problem is `devicesList = POINTER(c_char_p)()`. It's wrong because you define `devicesList` to be a pointer to a pointer, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes you right I think it's the main problem but how I can declare a table of pointer (of string) without using array (else my function is not compatible anymore) ?

Comment: It's problematic. In the C code you have an array of pointers. That array decays to a pointer to its first element when you pass it to the function. That's why the type `char **` works fine in the C code. I don't know how array decay works (if at all) with [ctype arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#arrays) but you should at least try to use it.

Comment: If I declare `devicesList` as a table of pointer, as following:
`devicesList = (POINTER(c_char_p)*10)()`
I have the error "expected LP_c_char_p instance instead of pointer to LP_c_char_Array_10"
I should to have a pointer on this table to pass to my function, but how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Some programmer dude I have solved my problem. Thank you.

I needed to declare a table. But `devicesList` must be declared as a table of pointer of `c_char`(not of `c_char_p`) and with a size. As my function need a pointer to the table I added a pointer named `pdevicesList` pointed on the first raw table. And it's this pointer that I use as parameter (by ref) of my function.

The complete and functionnal Python code is following:

```
  myDll= dllOpen(Dll)
  listDev = myDll.listDevices
  listDev.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(c_char_p)), POINTER(c_short)]
  n = c_short()
  devicesList = (POINTER(c_char)*10)()
  pdevicesList = devicesList[0]
  listDev(byref(pdevicesList),byref(n)) 
  for i in range(n.value):
     print ("-"+str(i)+": " + str(string_at(devicesList[i]),'utf-8'))
```

Result:
 -0: device0
 -1: device1

Perfect !!